# Display ones and zeros in an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The problem states that the user determines the size of the array, then based on the size you initialize the array elements to ones and zeros. How to initialize it?

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single loop: observe that you can get zero or one from a position by taking the remainder of division of an index by two, or by masking the index with `1`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != size ; i++) {
    A[i] = i % 2; // A[i] = i & 1; will work as well
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/skOjNe)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the 2nd for inside the 1st one. Simply use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    A[i] = (i % 2);
    std::cout << A[i];
}
```

Or use two cycle for fill and another one for print, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    A[i] = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < size; i += 2)
    A[i] = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    std::cout << A[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `std::vector` which is the right way to have an "array" whose size is specified at run time, you get zeros for free:

```
size_t size= ⋯ get the value from the user somehow ⋯
std::vector<int> A (size);
```

Every element of `A` contains the integer `0`.

If you want 1 in every element, use a second argument:

```
std::vector<int> B (size, 1);
```

Every element of `B` will contain the integer `1`.

See [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a good reference on the standard library classes.